# Separating objects in returned result by a comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping through a list of objects which i return to the user but i would like to add a comma between each of the objects but i am having trouble doing this appropriately.

this is how i am getting the objects:

```
function(self, classType){
    if(Array.isArray(classRoom.students)){
       self.students(classRoom.students.map(function(student){
          return new StudentViewM(student);
       }).join(', '));
    }
}
```

This is how my object looks:

```
self = Object { id: "5489443rjlb0ba113f5567533", className: "Art History"....}
student = Object { id:"khdjkhsdfieowe32323432", name: "John Smith"...}
```

This is my view:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: students">
     <span data-bind="text: studentName"></span>
</div>
```

Current Error:

```
Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return students }"(…)
```

Where can i appropriately add a comma so it will be displayed to the user that the objects are separated in display with comma.

Comment: lets see the list of objects...

Comment: `map()` creates an array, all you'd need to get a comma separated string is `.join()`

Comment: Additional context will be needed to formulate an answer to this question. We will need to see the objects in question. classRoom, self, and StudentViewM. It seems you are wanting the `,` in the display only. If that is the case we will need to see the display logic as well.

Comment: @JordanHendrix i have updated my post with more info - appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

With [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), possibly

```
self.students(classRoom.students.map(function(student){
    return new StudentViewM(student);
}).join(', '));
```

Comment: My guess is that this is what the OP was wanting.

Comment: by default  `join` joins by `','`

Comment: @isvforall, i know, but it looks bad.

Comment: i tried this but the error i am getting in my console is this: `Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return students }"(…)` I also updated my post with other information.